# How I can pass hardcoded location arrays to Mappls Direction Widget React Native?

Tags: react-native, mapmyindia-api

I need way-points like Pune-Bengaluru-Kerala  is there any prop to pass locations arr.
currently I have,

destination : {longitude:77.56,latitude:28.67,name:"MapmyIndia",address:"Okhla,New Delhi"},
source : {longitude:73.7228769,latitude:18.5248904,name:"Pune",address:"Pune,Maharashtra"},

currently my code look like this

```
const data = await MapplsDirectionWidget.openDirectionWidget({
        // destination : {longitude:77.56,latitude:28.67,name:"MapmyIndia",address:"Okhla,New Delhi"},
        // source : {longitude:73.7228769,latitude:18.5248904,name:"Pune",address:"Pune,Maharashtra"},
)}
```